# Grails: how to set data binding to use load method instead of get one?

Tags: grails, data-binding, lazy-loading, grails-orm

If i have a form such as bellow

```
<input type="text" name="someCollection[0].someAssociation.id"/>
<input type="text" name="someCollection[1].someAssociation.id"/>
<input type="text" name="someCollection[2].someAssociation.id"/>
```

Because Grails provides automatic data binding when it encounters a *.id* suffix, it seems Grails uses *get* method instead of *load* one which implies 3 queries as follows

```
SELECT * FROM SomeAssociationClass WHERE id = ?
SELECT * FROM SomeAssociationClass WHERE id = ?
SELECT * FROM SomeAssociationClass WHERE id = ?
```

I just need *load* method because it does not hit the database unless you use other than getId() (NOT APPLIED). So, how can i customize data binding so that it uses load method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid loading an instance of the database, we need to remove the *.id* suffix and register a custom propertyEditor which takes care of invoking *load* method

```
class AppPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(Question, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        @Override
            void setAsText(String value) {
                setValue(Question.load(value as Long))
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use command object to bind data when you submit your form.

```
@Validateable
class ExampleCO {
String username
// here will be your field name which you use on view ,both name will same as in domain class.
static constraints = {
username nullable: false
    // here you can provide same constraints as you define in your domain classes. It will also check validation on field here.

  }
}
```

in for you can write vale like this.

```
 <g:form action="saveSkills" method="POST">`
<g:textField name="name" id="skillName" class="skillName" value="${exampleCO?.username}"
                                 placeholder="Add your skill" style="width: 280px"/>
</g:form>
```

when you fill a form and hit an action to save it.name of field will same as name in command object. Then in action you can receive it in Command object like this,

```
def actionName(ExampleCO exampleCO){
  DomainClass domainClass = new DomainClass()
  binddata(domainClass,exampleCO)
 domainClass.save()
 }
```

Hope it will help,  if I understand your question very well.